# Hooking public member function of class(C_MORPHO_Device)

Tags: c++, hook

I have hooked a function **`GetUsbDevicesNameEnum()`** with my custom function **`MYGetUsbDevicesNameEnum()`**

My hooked function do get fired but the parameter of the function are not initialised properly.

I was expecting **sname** = "123456765-1234I086346" and **sprop** = "MORPHO device", but i get **`sname=NULL and sprop=""`**

what can be the problem?

[image]

**DLL Exports**

```
==================================================
Function Name     : const C_MORPHO_Device::`vftable'
Address           : 0x0000000180097148
Relative Address  : 0x00097148
Type              : Exported Function
==================================================

==================================================
Function Name     : public: int __cdecl C_MORPHO_Device::GetUsbDevicesNameEnum(unsigned long,char * __ptr64 & __ptr64,char * __ptr64 & __ptr64) __ptr64
Address           : 0x0000000180011f50
Relative Address  : 0x00011f50
Type              : Exported Function
==================================================
```

**myhook.h**

```
// hooked function typedefs
typedef INT(__cdecl* morpho_GetUsbDevicesNameEnum)(unsigned long, char * __ptr64 , char * __ptr64 );
extern "C" morpho_GetUsbDevicesNameEnum hook_GetUsbDevicesNameEnum= (INT(__cdecl*) (__in unsigned long,  char * __ptr64 , char * __ptr64 ))

....
```

**myhook.cpp**

```
 int main()
 {
  ... 
       // using mhook
       if (Mhook_SetHook((PVOID*)&hook_GetUsbDevicesNameEnum, MYGetUsbDevicesNameEnum))
       { // hook success}
  ...
 }

// my hook function
ULONG WINAPI MYGetUsbDevicesNameEnum(
unsigned long a,   // __in
char * __ptr64  sname,   // _out
char * __ptr64  sprop)   // _out
{
     // we are here but variables are not initialised properly
}
```

Comment: I believe your sname and sprop parameters are defined wrong.  It looks like you need to pass the address of the pointer.

Comment: i tried with modification  MYGetUsbDevicesNameEnum( unsigned long a, char* __ptr64 &sname,char* __ptr64 &sprop ) but still same results

Comment: do we have to do anything special for hooking class member function?

Comment: Member functions are different than non-member functions.  The above looks like it requires a non-member function.